# Which combinatorial class do noncrossing partitions belong to?

Tags: enumerative-combinatorics, generating-functions

Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer. The set $\lbrace 1,2,\ldots, n\rbrace$ is partitioned into blocks, with $p\left(n\right)$ possibilities (e.g., for permutations $p\left(n\right)=n!).$ For each block of size $i$, one of $m_i$ possible structures is chosen (for permutations, $m_i = \left(i-1\right)!$ since that's the number of ways to place $i$ elements in a cycle of size $i$).

> For noncrossing partitions, is there a relationship between the (exponential) generating function of $p\left(n\right)$ and that of $m_i$?

The combinatorial structures that I have seen are called assemblies, multisets, and selections, and they are classified by a relationship between the exponential generating functions of $\left(m_i\right)_{1\le n}$ and $p\left(n\right)$.

For example, for permutations (which is an example of an *assembly*), we have $m_i=\left(i-1\right)!$ and $p\left(n\right)=n!$. In this case, we have the exponential generating functions $$M\left(x\right)=\sum_{i\ge 1}m_ix^i/i!=\sum_{i\ge 1}x^i/i=\log\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$$
and
$$P\left(x\right) = \sum_{n\ge 0}p\left(n\right)x^n/n!=\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}=e^{M\left(x\right)}.$$

The relationship $P\left(x\right)=e^{M\left(x\right)}$ holds for all assemblies (not just permutations), and for this reason, assemblies are called *exponential families.*

I am looking for an analogous classification for the set of noncrossing partitions on $n$ distinct objects. However, I am unsure what relationship holds between $P$ and $M$.

**Approach:** Given $n$ distinct elements, there are $p\left(n\right) = C_n$ distinct noncrossing partitions, where $C_n$ is the $n$th Catalan number. Given $i$ elements, there is $m_i = 1$ way to place these $i$ elements in a block of size $i$ in a noncrossing partition. In this case, we have $M\left(x\right)=e^x-1$ and
$$P\left(x\right) = \sum_{n\ge 0}p\left(n\right)x^n/n!=\sum_{n\ge 0}C\left(n\right)x^n/n!=e^{2x}\left(I_0\left(2x\right)-I_1\left(2x\right)\right),$$
where $I_n$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Further, the usual generating function of $p$ is $$\sum_{n\ge 0}C_n x^n =\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-4x}+1}.$$

**More background:** In addition to permutations, the example of usual set partitions on $\lbrace 1,2, \ldots, n \rbrace$ also are an exponential family (which is why I wondered if noncrossing partitions fell into this class as well); for usual set partitions, we have $m_i=1$ since there's only $1$ way to place $i$ elements in a set of size $i$, and $p\left(n\right)=B_n$, the $n$th Bell number.

Comment: Perhaps what you want is given by Exercise 5.35 in *Enumerative 
Combinatorics*, vol. 2. It gives a noncrossing analogue of the exponential formula.